# What should my team and I learn first 2D or 3D?

Tags: rendering

Hello I am willing to start making a game about adventuring and saving the dream land of goats from nightmares.  I have a small team of people that go to the same school as I do and we are all at a variety of different levels in math and ELA. The team consists of about 10 people total and I was wondering how I should start.  Is 2D really easier than 3D?  One of the members know how to do 3D animation with blender or something like that and are willing to be the animation side of this.  This will have been all of our first games (complicated game to be exact) that we made and are unsure we can do it in the first place.  My and another bunch of the team have the basic storyline figured out and believe it will be about twice as long as The Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time.  We have about an hour all together then we are separated in classes but I have a ton of free time normally as I am done with everything fast for about another two hours.  Anyways the real question is,  Should we start 2D or 3D how much harder is 3D than 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what engine you want to use for development. If you where to use something like MonoGame or a barebones framework then 3D would be considerably more difficulty. However if you use a game engine like Unity or Unreal Engine it will be a lot easier, quite a lot of the math is already done, and the engines make setting stuff up a lot easier.

That being said if you have never programmed or programmed games before it might be a better idea to first learn the language you will use, working with a barebones framework doing 2D related stuff first (MonoGame or something else) might give you a better understanding of how stuff works and how to implement it better. That's up to you to decide though.

So yes in a nutshell 2D is definitely easier than 3D.